# Unnest elements from JSON array column

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, set-returning-functions, lateral-join

I have a Postgres table `test` like this:

```
id | data
---+----------------------------------
0  | {'0':'a','1':'b','2':'c'}
1  | {'0':'d','1':'e' }
2  | {'0':'f','1':'g','2':'h','3':'i'}
```

How to get the following output?

```
id | data
---+-----
0  | a
0  | b
0  | c
1  | d
1  | e
2  | f
2  | g
2  | h
2  | i
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`json_each_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in a `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT t.id, d.data
FROM   test t, json_each_text(t.data) d(key, data)
ORDER  BY t.id, d.key;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c41d58b81f04c5ec8f59bce6c2e3b4f1)*

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

However, what you display is *not* a JSON array, just a JSON object with key/value pairs, and with illegal syntax on top of it. Must be all double quotes ...